# How can features of SSL counter IP hijacking?

Tags: ssl

If an active, authenticated connection between two hosts is disrupted and the attacker takes the place of one of the hosts, how can SSL features help to counter or prevent?

Answer (score 3):

The two original hosts have agreed on a temporary secret key, so the host trying to hijack the connection would need knowledge of the key to stand in for one of the hosts. Otherwise it cannot send any message that will be seen as valid by the other side.

This is called the master secret (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6101#section-6.1).

So unless the Hijacker can break the encryption, he cannot simply hijack the connection.

If the disruption you mention means establishment of a new connection, the usual rules for certificate verification prevent an attacker from replacing one side (but only if client certificates are used and verified otherwise the client could be replaced). There are methods like certificate pinning to prevent using a different valid certificate, but those must be implemented.

Comment: can the session be disrupted and new connections established?  are there any differences?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find most answers to your question in [the introduction of the TLS specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-1).

When establishing the SSL/TLS connection, the two parties agree on a master secret, which is used to produce shared encryption keys and MAC secrets.

While the purpose of encryption is to ensure the confidentiality of the conversation, message integrity is protected by a [Message Authentication Code (MAC)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-5). The attacker wouldn't have the right MAC key to impersonate the legitimate host.

(Of course, that's only useful if the key exchange was properly authenticated in the first place.)